# Entering website pushes notification on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, web, push-notification

I want to make a Simple App. I’m a beginner in Swift, with Just basic knowledge, But I’m Very Good at PHP and JS, So basically, programming is not foreign to me.

The App should cowork with my website and it should do Only one thing. When person visits my web, I get a notification on my iPhone. Simple as that, yet I have no idea how to make it.

Any ideas, recommendations?

Any help Appreciated.

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way will be to use OneSignal service for Push Notifications. When somebody enters your site, you call method on OneSignal API via your PHP code. And it sends push to your app.

OneSignal API is here:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-api

Documentation about iOS integration is here:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

It is free and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take a look at it. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

That would require a bit of PHP and SQL (and everything similar). You can check out [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none).

Comment: Thanks! I already know Google analytics But the App I plan should be more complex after some time and I’d love to do it myself. If you have any PHP/SQL code, great! A Can code in it. :-)

Comment: @DavidStančík I sadly don't know PHP/SQL code, but I know what they are. Sorry.